# Finding integration limits for a volume (triple) integral

Tags: calculus, divergence-theorem

I want to verify the Divergence Theorem for the following:

We have a solid Cylinder $V = {(x, y ,z: x^2 + y^2 < 1}$ and $ 0<z<1$ and the vector field $F = (2-x-y)^2i + (3-x^2+y^2)j + x^3z^2k$

To do this I just need to evaluate a triple integral, howeve I am struggling to work out what the limits of integrations should be. I know that $0<z<1$, so therefore the last integral (third) would be between 0 and 1.. However because I am not given, $x$ and $y$ to be between something or equal to something I am unable to work the other 2 out... I just have that $x^2+y^2 < 1$ ...

Comment: Why last as $0<x<1$ ? where did y go and why did both $x$ and $y$ wen't down a power?

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Maybe this works, $-\sqrt{1-x^2} < y < \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $-1 < x < 1$?

Comment: maybe $y$ is correct, not sure about $x$ though, it lost it's power again :D

Comment: I think it should be okay since when $x$ is in $(-1,1)$, $x^2$ is in $[0,1)$.

Comment: @Oussema it doesn't say that $x$ is between $-1$ and $1$. It just says that $x^2+y^2 < 1$ so it could be between $-123<x^2+y^2<1$

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ and $y^2 \ge 0 \implies x^2 < 1 \iff -1 < x < 1$. Is my reasoning, but I could very well be wrong because as I said, I've never done multi-variable calculus.

Comment: $y^2$ is not $>1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123577/discussion-between-oussema-and-platinummaths).